# Docker-Compose Environment-Variables blank string

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm trying to get the Env-Variables in Docker-Compose to work. My Files:

env/test.env:

```
XUSER=you
XHOME=/home/${XUSER}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
    services:
     abc:
        build: .
        image: xyz:latest
        container_name: xyz
        env_file:
          - env/test.env
        user: "${XUSER}"
```

docker-compose up --build

docker-compose config

```
WARNING: The XUSER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
    services:
      kernel:
        build:
          context: xyz
        container_name: xyz
        environment:
          XHOME: /home/you
          XUSER: you
        image: xyz:latest
        user: ''
```

As you can see user: '' is an empty string, but the env_file works. I found some old Bug reports about this issue, I'm not sure I doing something wrong or not.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Although the other answers are both correct they do not highlight the underlying misunderstanding here enough:

With the [`env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file) option you can specify a file with variables to be injected into the environment *in the container*.

Using [*variable substitution*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) in the `docker-compose.yml` you can access variables in the environment *of the `docker-compose` command*, i.e. on the host.
You can set these using the usual mechanisms of your OS/shell, e.g. in `bash`:

```sh
export XUSER=you
docker-compose up
```

Additionally with `docker-compose` you can use a [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) *in the current directory*.

So in your concrete example you should just move `env/test.env` to `.env` to add the variables to the environment of `docker-compose` for *variable substitution*.
If you also want to add them to the environment in the container you can do it like this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  abc:
    build: .
    image: xyz:latest
    container_name: xyz

    # add variables from the docker-compose environment to the container:
    environment:
      - XUSER=$XUSER
      # or even shorter:
      - XHOME

    # use variable from the docker-compose environment in the config:
    user: "${XUSER}"
```

Comment: Note this also applies when using the `--env-file` command line option, e.g. `docker compose --env-file file.env`

Answer (score 19):

It says `WARNING: The XUSER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.` because `${XUSER}` doesn't exist at the time this is executed:

```yaml
user: "${XUSER}"
```

`${XUSER}` is not in your environment (you can verify this by running: `env | grep XUSER`, which should output nothing), and docker-compose didn't find any .env file at the same level or no .env file was passed at the time you ran `docker-compose up --build` or `docker-compose config`

### **Flexible solution:**

Rename `env/test.env` for `.env` and place it a the root of the folder container your `docker-compose` file so that docker automatically parses it.

Or use:

```sh
docker-compose --env-file path/to/env/test.env up --build
docker-compose --env-file path/to/env/test.env config
```

### **Permanent solution:**

Export them manually in your environment by running:

```sh
export XUSER=you && export XHOME=/home/${XUSER}
```

Or you use your `env/test.env` file as a source (note that you'll need to prefix with 'export'):

`env/test.env`:

```sh
export XUSER=you
export XHOME=/home/${XUSER}
```

And then your run `. /path/to/env/test.env` or `source /path/to/env/test.env`

Answer (score 10):

I also started encountering this after upgrading to Docker Desktop 4.12.0. This error started happening for quoted strings inside of `.env` (when using `env_file` to load variables in `docker-compose.yml`).  In that case, be sure to use single quotes instead of double quotes, i.e.

```
MY_VAR='foo$bar'
# ... instead of...
MY_VAR="foo$bar"
```

Comment: Oh wow!  This was it!  Thanks @patricknelson I lost two hours trying to hunt this down.

Comment: I was constantly encountering a varying number of the following warning (which didn't disrupt functionality):
`WARN[0000] The "ce080nC1" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

Comment: IF no single or double quotes will work?

Comment: To expand on this a little, both `MY_VAR="foo$bar"` _and _`MY_VAR=foo$bar` will result in the warning `WARN[0000] The "bar" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

Comment: this solved it for me. weird issue.

Answer (score 7):

What you need to do is create .env file at the same directory as your docker-compose.yml file, the content of ***.env*** is :

```
XUSER=user1
```

then run    `docker-compose config`

reference : https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `docker-compose config`, very handy

Answer (score 5):

Since +1.28 `.env` file is placed in project root,  not where docker-compose is executed.  If you do that the variables will be automatically pulled through to be available to the container.

This works great in dev, especially with a a bind-mount volume to make `.env` available to compose in project root without also going into image build by including `.env` in `.dockerignore`

But in production I was not comfortable including it in my project root especially since I was pulling those project files down from github. The Compose file expects them to be in the production environment to replace for substitution `SECRET_VAR=${SECRET_VAR}`

So one hack solution was to stick the `.env` file high in my production directory tree, far away from my project (ideally these would come from an environment store on the hosting service, or another encrypted store), but inject those variables into the container at runtime by using the `--env_file` flag in Compose up.

The `env_file` flag works Like this:
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml --env-file ../.env  up -d`

Its in [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option)

Answer (score 2):

##### Try this, I hope it will work.

- You need to escape the variable if you want it to be expanded inside the container, using a double-dollar sign `($${envVariable})`.
- If however, you want it to be interpreted on your host, the `$envVariable` needs to be defined in your environment or in the `.env` file. The env_file option defines environment variables that will be available inside the container only.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a better way to do this please let me know but a hack is as follows for docker compose

To create dynamic .env files you can do the following

1. create a cron job that runs at reboot eg:
   `crontab -u $USER -e`
2. append the following oneliner or similar where every env variable is seperated by a \n. the sleep here just waits 30secs for an ip address to be assigned

- `` @reboot sleep 30 && echo "MYIP=`ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet 10" | awk 'FNR==1{print $2}'`\nMYOTHERVAR=sometext" > <PATH TO DOCKER_COMPOSE FILE>/.env ``
- This will update the .env file on every reboot and in this case the ip address and text variable will overwrite the contents of the .env file

3. Then add

   ```
   env_file:
       - .env
   ```

to the docker-compose file

on reboot a file similar to the one below will be created

[image]